# Postgres SQL inner join syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Can some one please explain the inner join syntax in the SQL below:

```
 CREATE TABLE dataset AS 
  SELECT property.id 
       , amount.band
       , amount."value"
 FROM property  
 INNER JOIN (locality INNER JOIN amount ON locality.code = amount.code) ON (property.band = amount.band) AND (property.id = locality."UniqueId")
```

Why is the table `locality` defined before the second inner join? I've never come across such strange syntax.

Is there a more clearer way to right the same query so that someone can easily understand whats going on?

Comment: This syntax is not specific to Postgres. It is allowed by the SQL standard and I have seen this with SQL Server as well - although I never understood the benefit of doing a join this way.

Comment: That syntax was removed from the ANSI SQL standard in SQL-2003 or SQL-2008. BTW, value is a reserved word, it needs to be delimited as "value".

Comment: `... INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM locality INNER JOIN ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FROM property  
  INNER JOIN (locality INNER JOIN amount ON locality.code = amount.code)
     ON (property.band = amount.band) AND (property.id = amount."UniqueId")
```

is the same as

```
FROM property  
  INNER JOIN amount ON property.band = amount.band AND property.id = amount."UniqueId"
  INNER JOIN locality ON locality.code = amount.code
```

When `INNER JOIN`s only, you can re-order them as you want.

(Any specific reason to JOIN locality? You don't select any of its columns. Is it some kind of `EXISTS`, or do you want multiple rows returned if there are several matching rows in that table?)

Comment: I've updated the original sql - should have been `(property.id = locality."UniqueId")`. does that mean I need to move the `AND` to the locality join?

Comment: @ozzii, yes, move that condition. (You are not allowed to have ON conditions on tables not yet specified in the join-chain. Read from left to right.)